# When using lstat in c to get st_mode, file is a true for S_IFDIR even if its just a plain textfile

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, stat

When using opendir() on the following test directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Mai  4 22:55 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 foo foo 4096 Mai  4 22:59 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo   21 Mai  4 21:46 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo   18 Mai  4 21:46 baz.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo   12 Mai  4 21:45 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo    6 Mai  4 23:06 test.txt
```

and iterating over each of the files with

```
while (0 != (dirEntry = readdir(dirHandle))) { // loop over each file
```

using lstat on each file and store the result in the `attr` struct of type `stat`

```
struct stat attr;
lstat(dirEntry->d_name, &attr);
```

the following code results in not understandable behavior

`if (attr.st_mode & S_IFREG) { ... }`

false: on file bar and baz.txt and foo results in 0, no regular file.

`if (attr.st_mode & S_IFDIR) { ... }`

results in a number which is equal to S_IFDIR and the file is, 
therefore, a folder, even if it just contains some text.

test.txt results 0 for both somehow.

Why is it like that? Why is a plain text file a directory and what is the difference to a regular file?

All are just textfiles created with vim.

I was thinking, that in Linux all folders are textfiles, however, I need to distinguish them with normal files, if possible, with the method above.

### Source

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
// OPENDIR
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

struct dirent *dirEntry;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat mainStat;

    // Check usage
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (lstat(argv[1], &mainStat) == -1) {
        perror("lstat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    DIR *dirHandle;

    // Open the directory
    dirHandle = opendir(argv[1]);
    double size;
    // if 0 retrurn, error
    if(dirHandle) {
        while (0 != (dirEntry = readdir(dirHandle))) { // loop over each file
            // Check if the file is a directory
            struct stat attr;

            lstat(dirEntry->d_name, &attr);
            printf("%s: v:%d 1:%d2:%d \n", dirEntry->d_name, (attr.st_mode & S_IFREG), attr.st_mode, S_IFREG);

            if (strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, "..") == 0 || strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, ".") == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            printf("%s: v:%d 1:%d2:%d \n", dirEntry->d_name, (attr.st_mode & S_IFDIR), attr.st_mode, S_IFDIR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever check to see if `lstat()` succeeded? Your question needs a [MCVE], not just a few fragments of out of context code.

Comment: No, not yet, thanks I need to add this.

Comment: lstat: No such file or directory

Comment: Seems the error is that lstat cant find the file/directory.

Comment: Yea error fixed! Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path is not correct.

Using error handling, `perror` results in the error message `lstat: No such file or directory`

Prober error handling in C is very important, the solution is the following code with an absolute path rather than the relative:

```
 if(lstat("/home/foo/CLionProjects/untitled2/testdir/", &attr)==0) {
     perror("lstat");
 }
```